# Installation ionic Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=302

Tags: angularjs, express, ionic-framework

Hello I am working with Ionic and I want to install ionic using command

```
ionic start --v myapp tabs
```

But I am getting Error

```
Creating Ionic app in folder C:\Users\Ahmad\myapp based on tabs project
Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/archive/master.zip
Error with start Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=30
2
    at ClientRequest.onConnect (C:\Users\Ahmad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\
index.js:165:19)
    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitThree (events.js:97:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:175:7)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:352:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:536:20)
Error Initializing app: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, status
Code=302
 Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=302
    at ClientRequest.onConnect (C:\Users\Ahmad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\
index.js:165:19)
    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitThree (events.js:97:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:175:7)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:352:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:536:20)
```

I did R&D But not getting useful solution how to resolved that.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue.I am working with window 8 .I just find out the

environment variable  `https_proxy` and delete this variable then problem is

resolved